# SMTP seems to have duplicate security settings?

Tags: security, smtp

I'm new to setting up smtp, and I'm trying to figure out how to secure my server, but I'm getting a little turned around with all the security options - hopefully someone can help me clear this up. I'm using Windows 2008 R2 sp1 with IIS 7.5 if that makes any difference.

So what I'm seeing is, in the properties of the smtp virtual server I have an Access tab with an Authentication button. Seems to make sense, I pick Integrated Windows User, but then on the Delivery tab, I see an Outbound Security button which presents the same set of options again. I select Integrated Windows User.

Then, following the instructions I found online to setup smtp, I created a new domain under the smtp virtual server which then gave me ANOTHER Outbound Security tab with the same set of options. What are all these settings for? I've scoured google and couldn't find anything differentiating the 3 (maybe more?). I've found various sites that will tell me what one does or another, but they all seem to be doing the same thing and no site addresses that. Does one override another? Like a default for the server, but then specific ones for the domains or something like that? What's the difference between the Authentication and Outbound Security? What's the difference between the Outbound Security for the domain and for the main smtp server?

Oh, and one more question while we're semi on the topic - is the setup for domains mainly used for remote access? Like, it would be unnecessary for localhost use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two sets of authentications: inbound and outbound.

The Access tab lets you limit who and from where are allowed to access your SMTP server (i.e inbound), while the Outbound Security in turn lets you provide credentials that the SMTP service will use when delivering mails to another SMTP server (e.g. if relaying all outgoing emails to a smarthost that requires authentication).

You can furthermore set up remote domains, i.e. have emails for a specific domain be delivered to a specific server using specific credentials.

It is highly recommended to have all your outgoing emails forwarded to a smarthost that acts as an official email server for your sending domain, otherwise you risk your emails being classified as spam because they are sent from an unknown server.